# Can i get the same style for a div as i get on a button?

Tags: jquery

In jquery you could make a cool button with $("a").button(). It then gets a certain style base on the theme.

Is there are way i can style a div wrapping my content with the same style as my button? any classes to add?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're thinking of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com), rather than just jQuery.

Yes, you can apply the various theme styles to your own elements if you like. For example:

```
$("your selector here").addClass("ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all");
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/aduxo4)

The [theming page](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming) talks about the theme styles, you'll want to pick the ones that best suit what you're doing. The above is just an example set.